# Is there any way to configure tests to be launched against one specific simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testing

Right now, we are developing some snapshots testing. These tests save a screenshot of all the screens that have been tested and every time you launch the tests, will compare the screens with the screenshots previously saved. The problem is if you launch the tests choosing another kind of simulator (iphone 7 instead of XS) every test will fail because the size of the screen is different.

So my question is: Is there any way to configure the tests to be launched always against a specific simulator?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but you may want to try [SnappyTestCase](https://github.com/tooploox/SnappyTestCase) for agnostic snapshot tests.